# WP8 LongListSelector popluating list

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I've been trying to implement LongListSelector and I've been unable to find any good WP8 tutorial.

The best thing I've found is [WP7tutorial](http://students.cec.wustl.edu/%7Eacm/hackathon/LongListSelectorTutorial.html).
I've followed the tutorial till step 21, but my result isn't the same. I've ended up creating a list which only show categories in white text. which means it doesn't even uses the header template.

update: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) has a tutorial, but I think its way to advance for me since I'm also new to C#.

update2: I've figured out about why header template was not being displayed because "isGroupingEnabled" is disabled by default. [image: Enable is grouping in property pane].

Now groups are properly shown but not the items in groups [image: resulting UI]